# FlowType: Generic inheritance of multiple types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Imagine having two data types, both of them have an `id` property:

```
type Foo = {
  id: string,
  // other props
}

type Bar = {
  id: number,
  // other props
}
```

Now imagine a `Table` component in React which accepts an array of data as a property. This component needs to be generic, but we know that it requires an `id` prop for every data object in the data array. This `id` can either be a number or a string. The props might be typed as follows:

```
type Props = {
  data: Array<{id: number | string}>
}
```

The problem is that the above notation does not work. Is there a way to be able to 'retype' certain properties?

I have looked into [generic types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) but I can't seem to find a solution without changing the `Foo` and `Bar` type definitions.

Comment: Can you recreate this error on [Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/)

Comment: Are you just looking for a union `type U = Foo | Bar` and then `Array<U>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit too tricky for Flow to figure out I think. So instead of declaring a single property that both your types share, you can declare your array as containing types `Foo | Bar`.

This is nice because it has even less repetition than your original code, and in each branch of that if statement you have free access to other unique properties of `Foo` or `Bar` without any issues.

```
// @flow

type Foo = {
  id: string,
  // other props
}

type Bar = {
  id: number,
  // other props
}

type Props = {
  data: Array<Foo | Bar>
}

const foo: Foo = { id: 'A' }
const bar: Bar = { id: 1 }
const props: Props = { data: [foo, bar] }

for (const item of props.data) {
  if (typeof item.id === 'string') {
    console.log('I am a Foo')
  } else {
    console.log('I am a Bar')
  }
}
```

[Try Flow Link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMVrKALygDeiooAlgCYBcoAzigE5UB2A5gDQWgihYKABZYWoDC1gZGiAL7J02UACEAhuJLlKtBuwCuAWwBGY3pQFDR4ydNkLUmHAAUpM4mT401KNQwCCLCxqaAA8+IQAPqoaAHzyfIgAxrDszKCQBAwRHqTU9KAA5P6FoAopaSigxhoM6ppk+QwAjGXJqem2Mgyudrmg3r4MANqZsNzVGgC6bYiZ4gAUFelUKFiGgpASbowAdINqAJSeOlsLSliwW6vru7TERCSFzGxchcfalKDLsNBYu3BOAtCgBJUBqDZqPAEd58OSgLDQRg4T6UH5-AGwIGg8GQmIsWGUBRyIA)

Comment: This could be a solution. However, the drawback of this approach is that I have to update the type definitions of my `Table` component each time I decide to push a new type of data into it. I would prefer to have a more generic approach, where the data types and the `Table` component are not so tightly coupled.

Comment: @hannesbelen That means you want a record type with an`id` property that is associated with values of different type? This is barely a type anymore. You cannot have types and not have them at the same time.

Comment: @hannesbelen Then you can make a new type `type TableItem = Foo | Bar` and then your `Table` props become `data: Array<TableItem>`. Now in your types file you just have to keep up to date all the the items that are allowed to be a `TableItem`. You do have to be explicit about what types are allowed, that's sort of the whole point.